# Designing a reverse SOCKS relay in Python

Tags: python, sockets, http, proxy, socks

I have the following situation:

`WWW <- ServerBehindNAT(C) -> (S)MyApp(S) <- (C)BrowserUser`

**C** == Client connection.

**S** == Server connection.

**ServerBehindNAT** represents a node that connects via SOCKS to MyApp on my server.

**BrowserUser** represents a client browser with SOCKS proxy set as IP of MyApp.

**MyApp** represents this script which accepts incoming connection from BrowserUser, accepts incoming connection from ServerBehindNAT, and sends requests from BrowserUser through to ServerBehindNAT.

**WWW** represents the external Internet/www.

I have created a multi-threaded SOCKS server which listens on 2 ports. What I'm having trouble designing is the part where it forwards requests from BrowserUser through to ServerBehindNAT:

(S)<--(S)

The first code I had:

```
import logging
import select
import socket
import struct
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn, TCPServer, StreamRequestHandler, BaseRequestHandler
import threading
import mysql.connector

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
SOCKS_VERSION = 5


def sql_connect():
    """ database connection"""
    try:
        sql = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                      database='prox_main232',
                                      user='prox_main551',
                                      password='H20gN!vsi#rJ')
        if sql.is_connected():
            print('connected to sql')
            return sql
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False


def sql_auth(username, password):
        sql  = sql_connect()
        cursor = sql.cursor()
        query = "select `id` from partners where username = %s and password = %s"
        params = (username, password)
        try:
            cursor.execute(query, params)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error: ", e)


class ThreadingTCPServer(ThreadingMixIn, TCPServer):
    pass


class SocksProxy(StreamRequestHandler):
    username = 'username'
    password = 'password'

    def handle(self):
        logging.info('Accepting connection from %s:%s' % self.client_address)

        # greeting header
        # read and unpack 2 bytes from a client
        header = self.connection.recv(2)
        version, nmethods = struct.unpack("!BB", header)

        # socks 5
        assert version == SOCKS_VERSION
        assert nmethods > 0

        # get available methods
        methods = self.get_available_methods(nmethods)

        # accept only USERNAME/PASSWORD auth
        if 2 not in set(methods):
            # close connection
            self.server.close_request(self.request)
            return

        # send welcome message
        self.connection.sendall(struct.pack("!BB", SOCKS_VERSION, 2))

        if not self.verify_credentials():
            return

        # request
        version, cmd, _, address_type = struct.unpack("!BBBB", self.connection.recv(4))
        assert version == SOCKS_VERSION

        if address_type == 1:  # IPv4
            address = socket.inet_ntoa(self.connection.recv(4))
        elif address_type == 3:  # Domain name
            domain_length = ord(self.connection.recv(1)[0])
            address = self.connection.recv(domain_length)

        port = struct.unpack('!H', self.connection.recv(2))[0]

        # reply
        try:
            if cmd == 1:  # CONNECT
                remote = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                remote.connect((address, port))
                bind_address = remote.getsockname()
                logging.info('Connected to %s %s' % (address, port))
            else:
                self.server.close_request(self.request)

            addr = struct.unpack("!I", socket.inet_aton(bind_address[0]))[0]
            port = bind_address[1]
            reply = struct.pack("!BBBBIH", SOCKS_VERSION, 0, 0, address_type,
                                addr, port)

        except Exception as err:
            logging.error(err)
            # return connection refused error
            reply = self.generate_failed_reply(address_type, 5)

        self.connection.sendall(reply)

        # establish data exchange
        if reply[1] == 0 and cmd == 1:
            self.exchange_loop(self.connection, remote)

        self.server.close_request(self.request)

    def get_available_methods(self, n):
        methods = []
        for i in range(n):
            methods.append(ord(self.connection.recv(1)))
        return methods

    def verify_credentials(self):
        version = ord(self.connection.recv(1))
        assert version == 1

        username_len = ord(self.connection.recv(1))
        username = self.connection.recv(username_len).decode('utf-8')

        password_len = ord(self.connection.recv(1))
        password = self.connection.recv(password_len).decode('utf-8')

        if username == self.username and password == self.password:
            # success, status = 0
            response = struct.pack("!BB", version, 0)
            self.connection.sendall(response)
            return True

        # failure, status != 0
        response = struct.pack("!BB", version, 0xFF)
        self.connection.sendall(response)
        self.server.close_request(self.request)
        return False

    def generate_failed_reply(self, address_type, error_number):
        return struct.pack("!BBBBIH", SOCKS_VERSION, error_number, 0, address_type, 0, 0)

    def exchange_loop(self, client, remote):
        while True:
            # wait until client or remote is available for read
            r, w, e = select.select([client, remote], [], [])

            if client in r:
                data = client.recv(4096)
                if remote.send(data) <= 0:
                    break

            if remote in r:
                data = remote.recv(4096)
                if client.send(data) <= 0:
                    break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ####sql_connect() # connect to database
    print("Accept partner connections...")
    #with ThreadingTCPServer(('127.0.0.1', 9013), SocksProxy) as server:
    #    server.serve_forever()
    partner_server = ThreadingTCPServer(('127.0.0.1', 9013), SocksProxy)
    partner_thread = threading.Thread(target=partner_server.serve_forever)
    print("Accept app connections...")
    app_server = ThreadingTCPServer(('127.0.0.1', 9014), SocksProxy)
    app_thread = threading.Thread(target=app_server.serve_forever)

    for t in partner_thread, app_thread:
        t.start()
    for t in partner_thread, app_thread:
        t.join()
```

To conceptualize accepting inbound connection on both ports and sending request of one through the other (Making it a type of reverse proxy) is difficult to know the next step. I got the idea to communicate between two SOCKS server classes. I attempted that here:

```
import logging
import select
import socket
import struct
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn, TCPServer, StreamRequestHandler, BaseRequestHandler
import threading

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
SOCKS_VERSION = 5



class ThreadingTCPServer(ThreadingMixIn, TCPServer):
    pass


class NatServer(StreamRequestHandler):
    username = 'username'
    password = 'password'

    def __init__(self):
        NatServer.client = None
        NatServer.remote = None

    def handle(self):
        logging.info('Accepting app connection from %s:%s' % self.client_address)

        # greeting header
        # read and unpack 2 bytes from a client
        header = self.connection.recv(2)
        version, nmethods = struct.unpack("!BB", header)

        # socks 5
        assert version == SOCKS_VERSION
        assert nmethods > 0

        # get available methods
        methods = self.get_available_methods(nmethods)

        # accept only USERNAME/PASSWORD auth
        if 2 not in set(methods):
            # close connection
            self.server.close_request(self.request)
            return

        # send welcome message
        self.connection.sendall(struct.pack("!BB", SOCKS_VERSION, 2))

        if not self.verify_credentials():
            return

        # request
        version, cmd, _, address_type = struct.unpack("!BBBB", self.connection.recv(4))
        assert version == SOCKS_VERSION

        if address_type == 1:  # IPv4
            address = socket.inet_ntoa(self.connection.recv(4))
        elif address_type == 3:  # Domain name
            domain_length = ord(self.connection.recv(1)[0])
            address = self.connection.recv(domain_length)

        port = struct.unpack('!H', self.connection.recv(2))[0]

        # reply
        try:
            if cmd == 1:  # CONNECT
                remote = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                remote.connect((address, port))
                bind_address = remote.getsockname()
                logging.info('Connected to %s %s' % (address, port))
            else:
                self.server.close_request(self.request)

            addr = struct.unpack("!I", socket.inet_aton(bind_address[0]))[0]
            port = bind_address[1]
            reply = struct.pack("!BBBBIH", SOCKS_VERSION, 0, 0, address_type,
                                addr, port)

        except Exception as err:
            logging.error(err)
            # return connection refused error
            reply = self.generate_failed_reply(address_type, 5)

        self.connection.sendall(reply)

        # establish data exchange
        if reply[1] == 0 and cmd == 1:
            self.exchange_loop(self.connection, remote)

        self.server.close_request(self.request)

    def get_available_methods(self, n):
        methods = []
        for i in range(n):
            methods.append(ord(self.connection.recv(1)))
        return methods

    def verify_credentials(self):
        version = ord(self.connection.recv(1))
        assert version == 1

        username_len = ord(self.connection.recv(1))
        username = self.connection.recv(username_len).decode('utf-8')

        password_len = ord(self.connection.recv(1))
        password = self.connection.recv(password_len).decode('utf-8')

        if username == self.username and password == self.password:
            # success, status = 0
            response = struct.pack("!BB", version, 0)
            self.connection.sendall(response)
            return True

        # failure, status != 0
        response = struct.pack("!BB", version, 0xFF)
        self.connection.sendall(response)
        self.server.close_request(self.request)
        return False

    def generate_failed_reply(self, address_type, error_number):
        return struct.pack("!BBBBIH", SOCKS_VERSION, error_number, 0, address_type, 0, 0)

    def exchange_loop(self, client, remote):
        self.bridge_sockets(client, remote)
        while True:
            # wait until client or remote is available for read
            r, w, e = select.select([client, remote], [], [])
            if client in r:
                data = client.recv(4096)
                if remote.send(data) <= 0:
                    break
            if remote in r:
                data = remote.recv(4096)
                if client.send(data) <= 0:
                    break

    def bridge_sockets(self, client, remote):
        NatServer.client = client
        NatServer.remote = remote
        browser_server = ThreadingTCPServer(('127.0.0.1', 9013), BrowserServer)
        browser_thread = threading.Thread(target=partner_server.serve_forever)
        ''', kwargs={'app_client': client,
                     'app_remote': remote}'''
        browser_thread.start()
        #partner_thread.join()


class BrowserServer(StreamRequestHandler):
    username: "username"
    password: "password"

    def __init__(self):  # , app_client, app_remote
        self.app_client = NatServer.client
        self.app_remote = NatServer.remote

    def handle(self):
        logging.info('Accepting partner connection from %s:%s' % self.client_address)

        # greeting header
        # read and unpack 2 bytes from a client
        header = self.connection.recv(2)
        version, nmethods = struct.unpack("!BB", header)

        # socks 5
        assert version == SOCKS_VERSION
        assert nmethods > 0

        # get available methods
        methods = self.get_available_methods(nmethods)

        # accept only USERNAME/PASSWORD auth
        if 2 not in set(methods):
            # close connection
            self.server.close_request(self.request)
            return

        # send welcome message
        self.connection.sendall(struct.pack("!BB", SOCKS_VERSION, 2))

        if not self.verify_credentials():
            return

        # client request
        version, cmd, _, address_type = struct.unpack("!BBBB", self.connection.recv(4))
        assert version == SOCKS_VERSION

        if address_type == 1:  # IPv4
            address = socket.inet_ntoa(self.connection.recv(4))
        elif address_type == 3:  # Domain name
            domain_length = ord(self.connection.recv(1)[0])
            address = self.connection.recv(domain_length)

        port = struct.unpack('!H', self.connection.recv(2))[0]

        # reply
        try:
            if cmd == 1:  # CONNECT
                remote = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                remote.connect((address, port))
                bind_address = remote.getsockname()
                logging.info('Connected to %s %s' % (address, port))
            else:
                self.server.close_request(self.request)

            addr = struct.unpack("!I", socket.inet_aton(bind_address[0]))[0]
            port = bind_address[1]
            reply = struct.pack("!BBBBIH", SOCKS_VERSION, 0, 0, address_type,
                                addr, port)

        except Exception as err:
            logging.error(err)
            # return connection refused error
            reply = self.generate_failed_reply(address_type, 5)

        self.connection.sendall(reply)

        # establish data exchange
        if reply[1] == 0 and cmd == 1:
            self.exchange_loop(self.connection, remote)

        self.server.close_request(self.request)

        def get_available_methods(self, n):
            methods = []
        for i in range(n):
            methods.append(ord(self.connection.recv(1)))
        return methods

    def verify_credentials(self):
        version = ord(self.connection.recv(1))
        assert version == 1

        username_len = ord(self.connection.recv(1))
        username = self.connection.recv(username_len).decode('utf-8')

        password_len = ord(self.connection.recv(1))
        password = self.connection.recv(password_len).decode('utf-8')

        if username == self.username and password == self.password:
            # success, status = 0
            response = struct.pack("!BB", version, 0)
            self.connection.sendall(response)
            return True

        # failure, status != 0
        response = struct.pack("!BB", version, 0xFF)
        self.connection.sendall(response)
        self.server.close_request(self.request)
        return False

    def generate_failed_reply(self, address_type, error_number):
        return struct.pack("!BBBBIH", SOCKS_VERSION, error_number, 0, address_type, 0, 0)

    def exchange_loop(self, client, remote):
        # app_<-partner_client
        app_client = self.app_client
        app_remote = self.app_remote
        while True:
            # wait until client or remote is available for read
            #r, w, e = select.select([client, remote], [], [])
            r, w, e = select.select([client, app_client], [], [])
            if app_client in r:
                data = app_client.recv(4096)
                if client.send(data) <= 0:
                    break

            if client in r:
                data = client.recv(4096)
                if app_client.send(data) <= 0:
                    break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    nat_server = ThreadingTCPServer(('127.0.0.1', 9014), NatServer)
    nat_thread = threading.Thread(target=app_server.serve_forever)

    nat_thread.start()
    nat_thread.join()
```

I'm not sure if that's the right idea but it gave me the error when I connected to BrowserServer port via a web browser:

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 36632)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

Just so that everyone is clear on what I'm trying to accomplish: MyApp will run on a server and open 2 ports. ServerBehindNAT will be running client code which will maintain a connection to MyApp. BrowserUser will use MyApp server IP as a SOCKS server in his browser. When BrowserUser visits a site, the request will go through MyApp to ServerBehindNAT, who will process the request and send responses back through MyApp.

Comment: Why? Just use a normal SOCKS server and have *it* connect to the server behind the NAT device.

Comment: What do you mean? The connection has to be initiated by the server behind the NAT.

Comment: I'm not sure socks provides for making the inverted perma-connection you would need initiated by the server behind NAT. ssh provides a standard for that reversal tunnel (listener/forward) that can be mixed with its socks support when relevant.. I.e. on the NATed server either `ssh -R *:8080:localhost:80 myserver` or `ssh -R *:1080 myserver` to get either a transparent proxy or (perhaps too powerful) socks tunnel. If your natserver is using normal server architecture (i.e. it listens on a port) you will essentially be reimplementing ssh's tunnel protocol.

Comment: I don't find the failing `finish_request` method in the code you posted, nor the `RequestHandlerClass`. The error message looks like there's a simple programming error in that area, maybe through copy&paste from a different context.

Comment: pproxy is able to do this. I don't care about the protocol used to relay between MyApp and ServerBehindNAT. pproxy lets you choose http, socks, shadowsocks, etc. Last I tested it, I got it to work using HTTP and shadowsocks for ServerBehindNAT <-> MyApp. Of course browser must be able to connect on another port to MyApp. Problem with pproxy is that reverse connections don't work in their API, only their CLI tool.